# Neo4j Properties on relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Say I have two nodes "Body Temperature" and "Fever" , The relationship between them has name "causes" and property as "degree Celsius" has value "102.0" . Now What I want to do is write a cypher query in which if there is property value > 102.0  in MATCH clause then it must retrieve fever node otherwise not.

I have no idea of how to write such a query other then creating such structure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.9

Comment: 102 degrees celsius is above water boiling point, for sure that'll give you fever :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can filter on relationship properties like you would node properties, in the `WHERE` clause. Just make sure you bind the relationship to an identifier in the `MATCH` clause. I don't understand your model (is the temperature a property of the causation?) but you could try something like

```
MATCH (body_temperature) <-[r:CAUSES]- (fever)
WHERE r.degreeCelsius > 102
```

Is that what you are looking for?

**Edit**

To make a `CREATE` clause dependent on some condition you can state your condition as a pattern which only matches the cases where you want something created, and then just proceed to create. Just make sure that in your `START`, `MATCH` and `WHERE` clauses you bind the different nodes or relationships that you want to use in your `CREATE` clause. Sometimes you might have to use `WITH` to carry results to a new part of your query, but for your case first try something like

```
START bodyTemp = node:MyIndex(name="Body Temperature"), fever = node:MyIndex(name="Fever")
WHERE HAS(bodyTemp.degreeCelsius) AND bodyTemp.degreeCelsius > 102.0
CREATE bodyTemp -[:CAUSES]-> FEVER
```

Comment: Will this query create relationship between body temperature and fever if and only if degreeCelsius is greater than 102.0 ?

Comment: No, this matches a pattern already in the graph, filtering on a relationship property. Do you want to create the relationship if the "Body temperature" node has a value over 102.0 for its "degree Celsius" property?

Comment: Ya , I wanted to do that only . Sorry if i didnt write my question clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the "degree Celsius" is the property of the relationship "CAUSES", you can use the "where" clause to specify the property value constraint as follows,

```
Match t:BodyTemperature-[r:CAUSES]->f:Fever
Where r.degreeCelsius > 102.0
Return f
```

Comment: It seems I keep posting just one minute after someone else already answered :) I would bow out and delete my answer, except i think you may be assuming that Neo4j 2.0 is being used, is that right?

Comment: No need to delete your answer. I don't see any harm to have multiple answers. It happens quite often, and yes the use of labels requires 2.0.

Comment: Will this query create relationship between body temperature and fever if and only if degreeCelsius is greater than 102.0 ?